# Laravel 4 treating files as routes in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am just trying to host a laravel site to production. There is an error with the routing all my css and javascript files are being treated like a route instead of files and they are not loading

```
<script src='http://project.com/project/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js' type='application/javascript'></script>
```

I can see that this html is generated but the files are not being loaded When I click on the link I get a NotFoundHttpException

This is wroking fine in my local machine. This error is present only in live server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...so are the files *actually* there on your live server? If you are getting a 404 - it means they are probably not?

Comment: make sure you have updated the `app/routes.php` file and uploaded the controllers/modals/view files

Comment: @TheShiftExchange yes the files are there and Akshay, I have updated the routes.php and I have all the files in there. I am using git and I have pulled all the files to the server. it is just the copy of what I have in local. What can be the reason?

Comment: Have you entered correct entries for .htaccess file? i.e. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I am on nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is with nginx configuration. The root folder to the server was set incorrectly. So it was looking for differnt files. Not a code issue just and issue with the server environment

Answer (score 0):

The src link to your js file is set using Laravel's `HTML::script()`? If not change it because this will help so that you can have proper full urls for `js` and `css` files. So if you have a js file like `public/assets/js/custom.js` you should call it like this:

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/customs.js') }}
```

and you will be fine. Just remember that your starting point for assets is inside public folder. `HTML::script()` or `HTML::style()` get you there at once.

Comment: I moved the assets folder outside the of public..i.e. my `css` and `js` are in `assets/js` as opposed to `public/assets/js`. can this be an issue?

Comment: I tried the `{{ HTML::script('assets/js/customs.js') }}` but no effect..the still cannot get the files loaded